Problem with ALAMBIC animation and different shaders assigned to different vertex group
Here is the problem that I am facing :
export Alambic animation file from marvelous designer.
trying to assign specific shaders to different pieces of the fabric without going throught the UV way. > just want to add procedural shaders per specific items.
so far > I am able to do   VERTEX GROUPS selections and manually assign different shaders.
It's all good and working .
BUT ! . > and this is If I may say > a big but >
When I exit from EDIT MODE FACES.
The mesh goes BLANK MODE if i may say, like a BLANK SHADER "BY DEFAULT one". And I totally loose the benefits of creating those vertex group per farbric items .
here are 2 pictures showing the problem :


In advance, thank you very much.
Oops > I forgot to mention > This is happening on MOST RECENT VERSION of blender 4.2 beta. date 2024-07-08-19:36   hash : d527e3a6bd78    ... i will try on more "stable" 3.6.5 next..
yann

4.2 BETA is just that - a beta version and we can't help here. If you find it's ok in a previous Blender version I suggest you submit a bug report via the Help > Report a Bug menu in Blender so that it can be investigated before the release.

thank you very much for your feeback.   that is very true, and verified when I tried to perform the same operation in blender latest "OFFICIAL" 3.65   Hash cfleled46b7e date 23/10/16 14:30   >>> the described operation is working fine.

It might be an idea to try the 4.1.1 version before you submit a report just to make sure that the settings hadn't been changed when Blender 4 came out.

Thanks for the suggestion about trying in BLENDER 4.1.1.   just did it and it works totally fine. > I can't post a screen grab here any more apparently.    version of blender I did the test is :  Hash  e1743a0317bc    DATE : 2024-04-15  15:11



sinceres appologies for this useless report error message > now during those tests I realised that I probably did something very wrong >>> I was also testing the " REMOVAL OF FACES " on the alambic to save memory/space on the render. (me OVERTHINKING :)   > prior to do the shadin, all that Inisde blender 4.2 beta.   >> I must admit, to play with the NEW EVEE render...    big MISTAKE on my side ! >>  BECAUSE  I realised there the situation of the DIFFERENCE between EDIT MODE where the shader attribution of the FACE SELECT GROUP was working > BUT NOT later when IN   " OBJECT MODE ".






is the SAME in ALL VERSION OF BLENDER.   3.6.5,  4.1   4.2 beta. and evant 4.3 .  just test it again and again,  ervery version I go >> each time I want to delecte a faces > it corrupts somehow the ALAMBIC losing all knowledge of the vertex group...  >>  so I am creating a problem situation, and will avoid that in the futur ;))   my surprise is still there on the fact that in each version ;)) > in edit mode the shader attribution per FACES is still " working"  and goes "blank" when exiting this mode to object mode.   so >> this is problably a    NO PROBLEMO situation to report I assume ;)



